# Column(s) calculation

Tags: html, css

I would like to know what is the calculation for columns

**NOTE:** 
I am using **skeleton 2.0.4**,
**960 grid system (12 columns)**

Here is what I am trying to do:

- Inside the four column div I want to add two 2columns div which is seen on the picture colored white.

[image]

BUT....having this code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="header four columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="class two columns" style="background-color:white;">2 columns</div>
        <div class="class two columns" style="background-color:white;">2 columns</div>
        <div class="class two columns" style="background-color:white;">2 columns</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-top eight columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
        <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
        <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
        <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Those (white) 2 columns should be bigger than they are. So I am trying to achieve that bigger box or column. Hope you get my point here.

Problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, But based on how most grid systems work, maximum columns in this case 12 is always 100% width of its container. So to create two columns inside that div they should actually be 6 columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header four columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="class six columns" style="background-color:white;">2 columns</div>
      <div class="class six columns" style="background-color:white;">2 columns</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-top eight columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
      <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
      <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
      <div class="three columns" style="background-color:white;">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this will give you the two columned layout you seek inside the left div.

Comment: Oh Great! Thanks Jack! never knew that division is needed for this one. Sorry im just a newbie on Responsive pages. 

Anywyas.. So, everyime I make a column it is automatically a 12 column div already right?

Comment: Not exactly, when you make a div it is however many columns you specify It to be so 8 columns for example.

Then inside this div you have to split that div into 12 columns again. so 4 columns would be a third of this div, or 6 would be half or 12 would be the full width.  so the columns/grid is relative to the container your in.